# Insert each array into separate divs

Tags: php

I just need some advise before i start this. Basically I have an array of data of books from mysql -
ID,Name,genre,ratings
they are print out in an array like this

```
Array ( [book] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => book one [2] => horror [3] => 8.9 ) ) 
Array ( [book] => Array ( [0] => 2 [1] =>book two [2] => Comedy [3] => 8.3 ) ) 
Array ( [book] => Array ( [0] => 3 [1] =>book three [2] => Comedy [3] => 8.7 ) )
```

And so on..
How do i put each array in seperate divs?

PS PHP code to fetch data

```
$query=mysql_query("SELECT*FROM book ");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
$book= Array("book" => Array($row['id'], $row['name'],$row['genre'],$row['ratings']));echo"<br>";
print_r( $book);
```

Thanks

Comment: Where does *JavaScript* come in here?

Comment: Are you sure it is `tvshow`? It does not make sense with `book` indicated in the beginning of the question.

Comment: Sorry thats something different. But thanks i m going to try using loops

Answer (score 2):

You can use `foreach` for this:

```
foreach ($your_array['book'] as $v) {

  echo "<div>";
  echo "name: ". $v[1];
  echo "category: ". $v[2];
  ...
  echo "</div>";

}
```

It will loop along your array and let you work with values inside them.

Comment: Too non-constructive for the OP's question. -1

Comment: Why non-constructive?

Comment: The OP has loose arrays. You might ask the OP first what his code is. Maybe it's an issue resolving the way the the values are read out. It's highly likely a problem how the OP fetches his MySQL result.

Comment: I am answering the question _How do i put each array in seperate divs?_. Of course some improvements can be done from the way data is fetched, but it is not asked here.

Comment: @Allendar The OP is not describing any problem. It seems plain enough the OP is looking for a way to output the arrays.

Comment: Please @shell, update your question so the format will be easier to read!

Comment: There you have it. Even tho it wasn't specified, the foreach loop wouldn't help the OP at all. It just needs to handle the values inside the while-loop differently. I'll remove the `-1` when the answer is properly solving the problem. I could paste these solutions on half of the questions posted on StackOverflow. It doesn't help the OPs in any way to just post "general" code.